# set file permissions on bash output

Tags: bash, file-permissions

I have script to backup a mysql database. However I would like to set the file permissions to 755. I have done this in the script but it outputs a message. The part of the script is below

```
FILE="$BACKUPDIR/$NOW-$db.gz";
            echo "BACKING UP $db";
            $MYSQLDUMP --add-drop-database --opt --lock-all-tables --set-gtid-purged=OFF -u $MUSER -p$MPASS -h $MHOST -P $MPORT $db | gzip > $FILE

# change permissions on file
chmod 755 $FILE
```

The message I get is;
`chmod: missing operand after ‘755’`

Any ideas?

Comment: If chmod complains it is missing the operant, it means that `$file` has not been set. Print the `"$file"` variable just before chmod command and see what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume that value of $FILE is empty, or something different from what you expect.

Output the value of $FILE in your script to confirm that it has the value you expect.

You should use

```
chmod 755 "${FILE}"
```

to help avoid problems with spaces/strange characters in the filename

Comment: I still get the same message

Comment: And what is the value of $FILE?

Comment: 2016-10-13-14:12-customer_live.gz